# Rotational Velocity and Rotational Frequency

Tags: rotational-dynamics, frequency

What is the difference between rotational velocity & rotational frequency? Their units seem to be the same, and I've read that one is a 'scalar' and the other is a 'vector,' but how do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists indeed a subtle difference, and are often referred to as angular frequency and angular velocity. Both are $\omega$ and have units $\text{s}^{-1}$.

The difference lies in the fact that angular frequency is the magnitude of angular velocity, and is hence a scalar-, instead of vector quantity. The direction of the vector is perpendicular to the plane of rotation.

The angular velocity is actually a pseudovector, and has units $\text{rad s}^{-1}$, but usually the terms are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

A vector quantity has a direction and a magnitude. The direction of the rotational velocity vector is along the axis around which a body is rotating. Its magnitude is the rotational frequency which tells you how fast the body is rotating.